# How to launch an activity twice?

Tags: android

I have two entry points for my app. One is the main launcher and the other using an intent action.

The main launcher starts a root activity, which in turn launches activity A. Activity A can launch the root activity again. And I end up with an activity stack like this:

```
Hist #3: Activity A
Hist #2: Root Activity 
Hist #1: Activity A
Hist #0: Root Activity (launcher)
Task 1
```

The reason android tolerates duplicate activities in the same task is because the two root activities differ by their launcher attribute. This is exactly what I want.

However, if I launch the app using an intent action. After redirection I will end up in the root activity again. This time I cannot have duplicate activities.

```
// Attempt to start root activity here will end up bring Hist #0 to the front
Hist #1: Activity A
Hist #0: Root Activity (redirected, not launcher)
Task 1
```

In the second case, how can I have duplicate root activity?

I tried using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`, which gave me the following stack:

```
Hist #1: Activity A
Hist #0: Root Activity
Task 2
Hist #1: Activity A
Hist #0: Root Activity
Task 1
```

It works to some extent but it also leads to issues with backgrounding the app, so I am trying to avoid this approach.

**EDIT:** Here are some code:

AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.opentext.m.core.launch.MainRootActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="com.opentext.m.core.launch.IntentLauncherActivity"
    android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
    android:taskAffinity="">
    <!-- prod-na -->
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
        ...
        />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

MainRootActivity:

```
@MainThread
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // ...
    final Intent targetIntent = createTargetIntent();
    startActivity(targetIntent);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Intent createTargetIntent() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
    // ... (intent extras)
    return intent;
}
```

IntentLauncherActivity.kt:

```
internal fun redirect() {
    // ...
    val rootIntent = Intent(this, MainRootActivity::class.java)
    rootIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    rootIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
    // ... (intent extras)
    startActivity(rootIntent)
}
```

ActivityA.kt:

```
internal fun startRootAgain() {
    val rootIntent = Intent(this, MainRootActivity::class.java)
    rootIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    // rootIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK)
    startActivity(rootIntent)
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @TheWanderer There you go.

Comment: Can I ask why you want multiple instances of the same Activity? As a potential end user, it'd just confuse me having to back through multiple of what looks like the same Activity to me.

Comment: ActivityA is a file browsing activity. It contains a "Favourites" fragment that can offer shortcuts to some folders. When the user click on a shortcut, ActivityA is created again as an activity pop-up to browse in that folder.

Comment: Why not just change the contents of the Activity instead, or use Fragments?

Comment: The reason I am using MainRootActivity to launch ActivityA is because it does additional checks about login status etc..

Comment: In that case, it would definitely be easier to just change the contents of ActivityA or use Fragments. If you use the support library's (called androidx now) AppCompatActivity and Fragment, you can implement transition animations and such.